# end_time returns differently with developer api key than access_token in facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get different results when fetching the event information in the cases below. 
In the first example end_time is missing, but not in the second.

1)

Here is what I get when I do a graph api request for event 335236606550968 with my api key through facebook php library. I get this by doing var_dump( $facebook->api("335236606550968"));

```
       array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "335236606550968"
      ["owner"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(13) "SourceTech AB"
        ["category"]=>
        string(17) "Internet/software"
        ["id"]=>
        string(15) "177255652292215"
      }
      ["name"]=>
      string(21) "SourceTech Forum 2012"
      ["description"]=>
      string(146) "Missa inte SourceTech Forum som kommer ge er ett par fantastiska dagar späckade med inspiration, fantastiska möten och motiverande diskussioner."
      ["start_time"]=>
      string(10) "2012-10-17"
      ["location"]=>
      string(38) "Täby park hotell, Hotell & Restaurang"
      ["venue"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(15) "121351554601098"
      }
      ["privacy"]=>
      string(4) "OPEN"
      ["updated_time"]=>
      string(24) "2012-07-02T11:50:38+0000"
    }
```

2)

Here is what I get through a api call with my own users access_token when loading this URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/335236606550968?access_token=YOURACCESSTOKENHERE

```
    {
       "id": "335236606550968",
       "owner": {
          "name": "SourceTech AB",
          "category": "Internet/software",
          "id": "177255652292215"
       },
       "name": "SourceTech Forum 2012",
       "description": "Missa inte SourceTech Forum som kommer ge er ett par fantastiska dagar sp\u00e4ckade med inspiration, fantastiska m\u00f6ten och motiverande diskussioner.",
       "start_time": "2012-10-18T02:00:00",
       "end_time": "2012-10-19T02:00:00",
       "location": "T\u00e4by park hotell, Hotell & Restaurang",
       "venue": {
          "id": "121351554601098"
       },
       "privacy": "OPEN",
       "updated_time": "2012-07-02T11:50:38+0000"
    }
```

In the first example end_time is missing, but not in the second. 
This seems to be the case with most events that has an end_time that are on next day start_time. How do I retreive proper end_time for this event when using the php library with my API key?